# Ionic 4 App launcher launches most recent app instead of my app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to launch my own app when a shake gesture is registered. 
I am using cordova background-mode and cordova-shake and cordova app launcher.

the shake method is called in the background method and the app launcher is called in the shake method.

the problem is the code works perfectly with another apps package id, i.e com.facebook.katana.

However when I parse my App's package name, it doesen't work instead the phone launches the app that is the most recent in the task list.

has anyone else encounted this issue and resolved it or can someone take a look at my code and tell me if something is wrong.

```
startBackgroundMode(){          

    this.backgroundMode.enable();
    this.backgroundMode.overrideBackButton();           

    this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(value => { 
      this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations(); 
         this.platform.resume;
        this.shakePhone();   
    });
}
shakePhone(){
  this.shake.startWatch().subscribe(() => {
    console.log(`watching...`);   

    //this.backgroundMode.moveToForeground();               
    this.openApp();
    });

}
  openApp(){  

    const options: AppLauncherOptions = {
    }
    options.packageName = 'my apps package name that I got from the config.xml'


  this.appLauncher.canLaunch(options).then((launch)=>{
    if(launch){
      this.appLauncher.launch(options).then((launcher)=>{
        console.dir(launcher);
      }),(err)=>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      };
    }
    else{
      console.log("can't open app!");
    }
  }).catch((e)=>{
    console.log(e);
  });

  }
```

and the background mode is called in the constructor method of the app.component.ts file

### Edit

So I have played around with the app to try and understand whats happening.
What happens is that if I close my app in its in the background, and then if I open up another app, i.e memo and I minimize that app, and shake the phone then that app opens up, but if I press the back button again on that app and shake the phone again then my app opens up, I do not understand why its doing that?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app, and installing again?

Comment: Yes several times

Comment: Can you try in another device/emulator?
or maybe even change the app id from config and check

Comment: I have done some more test, and the logic works, however if you open an app, i.e memo or calculator or anything else. and you tap the backbutton, then shaking the phone will open my app, however if you tap the home button on another app and it takes you to the home page and then you shake the phone, then the last app in the task list will open